# Counting specific chars in C?

Tags: c

```
while ((temp = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
  {

  if(temp == '\n')
  {
      chars++;
      lines++;
      if((temp = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && (temp == '(' || temp == ')' || temp == '{' || temp == '}'))
          {
              chars++;
              brackets++;
          }
      }
  }
```

Basically I want to count every (),{} and lines in a random c file. This loop counts the lines just fine but fails to count all the specified symbols. Any idea why this is?

Comment: By fails, do you mean an inaccurate value is returned?

Comment: Does it count lines fine? What if you get two newlines in a row?

Comment: Why don't you have just one loop with no nesting, and `switch` on the value returned from `getc`, to classify the characters and update various counts. Make sure the variable is of `int` type so it can capture the value `EOF`.

Comment: An inaccurate value is returned yes. Sorry i should have specified that. And yes it counts lines just fine

Comment: @Kaz can you be a little more specific and even maybe give me an example, because i don't catch your drift

Comment: You only count parentheses and braces when they appear immediately after a newline because of the way the `if` is structured.  The simplest thing is to create an array of 256 integers initialized to zero, and increment the count for each character as it is read.  At the end, you can print out the counts you're interested in.  `while ((temp = getc(fp)) != EOF) { chars++; array[temp]++; }` and then print the values for `array['\n']` (newlines), `array['(']` (open parentheses), etc.  Or you can add `array['('] + array['{'] + array[')'] + array['}']` to get all the parentheses and braces in one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a simple state machine structure like:

```
int ch;

while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
  switch (ch) {
  case '\n':
     chars++;
     lines++;
     break;
  case '(': case ')': /* ... */
     chars++;
     brackets++;
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I didnt see your answer. We were some seconds apart.

Comment: @user3151488 If you add a "current state" variable to this set up, you can match any regular language with this because you can implement a general DFA (deterministic finite automaton), which is basically a big switch on the combination of current state and input symbol.  E.g. you could count how many C language tokens there are in the input, or whatever. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((temp = getc(fp)) != EOF)
{
   chars++;
   if(temp == '\n')
   {
      lines++;
      continue;
   }
   if(temp == '(' || temp == ')' || temp == '{' || temp    == '}')
   {
          brackets++;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((temp = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if(temp == '\n')
        lines++;
    else if (temp == '(' || temp == ')') // include other brackets
        brakets++;

    chars++; // it appears that you want to count them all?
}
```

Comment: Thanks that also works and looks simple enough :). By the way any idea how to count commented characters?

Comment: @Vlad What do you mean by "commented characters"?